# Можно ли сказать "оказывать сервис"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Сервис - это обслуживание. И вот мне недавно в тексте попалось словосочетание "оказывать сервис". Мне кажется, что оно неверное. Я бы написала "осуществлять сервис" или "предоставлять", хотя, признаться, эти варианты мне тоже кажутся неуклюжими.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильнее сказать в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из словаря
СЕРВИС, -а; м. [англ. service]
Сфера обслуживания населения; совокупность учреждений по удовлетворению бытовых нужд и оказанию таких услуг. Служба сервиса. Гостиничный, автомобильный сервис. Сервисное обслуживание населения.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Значение слова расширяется: вместо выражения "сервисное обслуживание" мы используем слово "сервис" со значениями "обслуживание" или обозначаем этим словом  сами услуги. Такой "сервис" можно обеспечивать, предлагать, предоставлять, также можно организовать сервис.

Например: "WebMoney Transfer предоставляет сервис по выдаче и обслуживанию банковских карт международных платёжных систем (МПС)". "Увы, но современный сервис организован либо индустриально (на основе жесткой специализации и стандартизации), либо доиндустриально, как ремесло".

Но сочетаемость сервиса/сервисного обслуживания/сервисных услуг с другими словами представляется еще  неполной, поэтому "осуществлять сервис" - нежелательно, "оказывать сервис" - неверно. Можно сказать: осуществлять сервисное обслуживание, оказывать сервисные услуги.